# Component doesnt update view properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Render does indeed get called and even though the debugger shows that `temp` is populated properly, the change doesnt seem to take place (the json string doesnt make it to the dom). I am probably missing something obvious.

```
class ProfileComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        this.props = props;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        window.mainStore.subscribe(this.render.bind(this))
    }

    render() {
        var temp = JSON.stringify(window.mainStore.getState().profile);
        return (
            <div>
                {temp}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Debugging looks like :

[image]

Comment: looks like you have a typo for `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: sorry, thats not in my local code, just missed it here.

Comment: What happens when you do `console.log(temp)`? before your return statement?

Comment: just added an image to show just that

Comment: doesnt seem like its an issue with it simply not displaying in the dom , i know that because a = "tesT" works perfectly fine as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the first time 'ProfileComponent' rendered we don't have the subscribe method, after the componentDidMount we see the correct result , lets try to add a state which blocks the first render to return invalid {temp}:

```
class ProfileComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { loading: true, temp:''};
    }
 componentDidMount() {     
      window.mainStore.subscribe(); // I don't see all your code but i think here we don't need to bind the render because the component will render after again after changing the state (you can try it both)
      const temp = JSON.stringify(window.mainStore.getState().profile); // better keeping 'window' logic here (especially if our app is SSR) 
      this.setState({loading: false,temp});
    }
 render() {
    const {loading, temp} = this.state;
    if(loading) {return (<div>Loading...</div>)}
    return (
        <div>
            {temp}
        </div>
    );
}
};
```